# Strange crash while adding to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The application crashes on the row:

```
[uids addObject:user.uid];
```

Who can tell why??
[image]

Comment: Can you specify the crash error message

Comment: unfortunately there is no error message! (I don't really know why - may be it's some Xcode settings...)

Comment: @Stas I thought you could add only of type `id` i always get a warning with adding integer or float values. Do you get warning during build ?

Comment: Try to add this to debug window and try again? http://d.pr/a6Zq+

Comment: @iNoob, Its a NSNumber not integer or float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[uids addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.uid]];
```

I am not sure if this will help or not

Answer (score 1):

When you add an object into an array, whatever you add must be a subclass of NSObject. 
You can't add into an array float, int, double or so on. 
You can add, NSString, NSNumber, etc. or any object of your own that inherits from NSObject.

(BTW, if you hit On "Continue" after the thread stops, you'll the error. You probably have setup in XCode global breakpoints for exception throw, and that's why you get the breakpoint first, then get thrown an exception)

Comment: he is adding a NSNumber not basic data types

Comment: the type of object is NSNumber...I don't click Continue - I click step over. And the error message is EXC_BADACCESS...I think the problem is in retaining an object by array...smth like this..

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are trying to add nil object.
Or if you are trying to add already released object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you allocated and initialized the NSMutableArray?

```
uids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
```

Comment: as you can see from screenshot I did it.
p.s there is no way to zoom an image in SO. just zoom your browser

Comment: I understood that that's why i posted p.s in the comment above)

Answer (score 0):

seems like a xcode fail. try to clean and restart xcode.